# Hide Header Row in classic report Oracle Application Express 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I would like to hide the header row (that contains column titles) in a classic report. I am using Oracle Apex 5.1

I would like to hide the header row AC,AD etc.  Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solved: Attributes : Heading -> None

Comment: ??? "Heading -> None" ? There's only "Fixed To" option under Reports's Attributes / Heading. And it changes nothing on the report... :-(

Answer (score 1):

My solution, in inline css add:

```
.a-IRR-header{
    display:none;
}
```